# Can we add an extension using python sdk compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update to Azure VM it creates?

Tags: python, azure, sdk, virtual-machine

Morning,

I have a need to have the AADLoginForLinux extension added to the vms I spin up with the python sdk compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update call.

I see I could maybe do a rest call to add extensions, but I was wondering if it could be done with the sdk call instead?  Anybody have a sample/example of adding an extension like this?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure Virtual Machine using the below code:

```py
credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = "XXXXXXXX"
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME = "Imran"
LOCATION = "eastus"
rg_result = resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
{
"location": LOCATION
}
)

VNET_NAME = "testvnet"
SUBNET_NAME = "subnet1"
IP_NAME = "IP"
IP_CONFIG_NAME = "ipconfig"
NIC_NAME = "testnic"
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
poller = network_client.virtual_networks.begin_create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
VNET_NAME,
{
"location": LOCATION,
"address_space": {
"address_prefixes": ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
}
)
vnet_result = poller.result() 
poller = network_client.subnets.begin_create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
VNET_NAME, SUBNET_NAME,
{ "address_prefix": "10.0.0.0/24" }
)
subnet_result = poller.result(
print(f"Provisioned virtual subnet {subnet_result.name} with address prefix {subnet_result.address_prefix}")
poller = network_client.public_ip_addresses.begin_create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
IP_NAME,
{
"location": LOCATION,
"sku": { "name": "Standard" },
"public_ip_allocation_method": "Static",
"public_ip_address_version" : "IPV4"
}
) 
ip_address_result = poller.result() 
poller = network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
NIC_NAME,
{
"location": LOCATION,
"ip_configurations": [ {
"name": testconfig,
"subnet": { "id": subnet_result.id },
"public_ip_address": {"id": ip_address_result.id }
}]
}
)
nic_result = poller.result()
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
VM_NAME = "linuxvm"
USERNAME = "****"
PASSWORD = "****" 
poller = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME,
{
"location": LOCATION,
"storage_profile": {
"image_reference": {
"publisher": 'Canonical',
"offer": "UbuntuServer",
"sku": "16.04.0-LTS",
"version": "latest"
}
},
"hardware_profile": {
"vm_size": "Standard_DS1_v2"
},
"os_profile": {
"computer_name": VM_NAME,
"admin_username": USERNAME,
"admin_password": PASSWORD
},
"network_profile": {
"network_interfaces": [{
"id": nic_result.id,
}]
}
}
) 
vm_result = poller.result() 
print(f"Provisioned virtual machine {vm_result.name}")
```

***Azure Virtual Machine got created successfully like below:***

[image]

To add the Extension while creating Azure Virtual Machine, make use of **`VirtualMachineExtensionsOperations`** Class like below:

```py
VirtualMachineExtensionsOperations(*args, **kwargs) 

begin_create_or_update
(resource_group_name: str, 
vm_name: str, vm_extension_name: str, extension_parameters: _models.VirtualMachineExtension, *, 
content_type: str = "'application/json'", **kwargs: Any) -> 
LROPoller[_models.VirtualMachineExtension]
```